# Не работает LIKE в SQL-запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть `DropDownlist` c отступом:

```
Все
XXX
 XXX
  XXX
XXX
 XXX
```

Запрос:

```
declare
@name  nvarchar(100) = ' XXX'
begin 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
  FROM dbo.test 
  where (@name = 'Все' or name Like '%'+@name+'%')
  end
```

В таблице есть строка `XXX` без отступа.
В параметр `@name` передается значении с пробелами(к примеру `'  XXX'`, `' XXX'`)
Как сделать чтобы оператор like работал?

Comment: а вот так работает?  Like N' XXX%'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если проблема в пробеле - то проще всего его обрезать:

```sql
declare
@name  nvarchar(100) = ' XXX'
begin 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
  FROM dbo.test 
  where (@name = 'Все' or name Like '%'+RTRIM(LTRIM(@name))+'%')
  end
```

Comment: Проблема не в пробеле. Пробел - это уже следствие куда большей проблемы модели данных.

Comment: @Sergey согласен - сам по себе like - это признак что что-то идет не так.

Comment: @ PashaPash, вместо like, точный поиск было бы идеально

Comment: @Zhandos значит вам надо перестраивать модель. например, хранить отсутп в отдельном поле в таблице (Level), и дорисовывать пробелы перед отображением на UI. а при поиске - вырезать. Или, возможно, вообще отказаться от использования отображаемых строк для поиска - все дропдауны позволяют явно указать отдельно поле данных и отдельно поле для значения.